# Docker network does not work with bash entrypoint

Tags: bash, selenium, docker, dockerfile

First, we have a Docker network like so:

```
docker network create cdt-net
```

Then I have this bash script which will start a selenium server:

```
cd $(dirname "$0")
./node_modules/.bin/webdriver-manager update
./node_modules/.bin/webdriver-manager start
```

The above bash script is called by this Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:latest

RUN apt-get update && \
      apt-get -y install sudo

RUN mkdir -p /root/cdt-webdriver
WORKDIR /root/cdt-webdriver

COPY start-selenium-server.sh .

ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "/root/cdt-webdriver/start-selenium-server.sh"]
```

I would build it like so:

```
docker build -t cdt-selenium .
```

and then run it like so:

```
docker run --network=cdt-net --name cdt-selenium -d cdt-selenium
```

the problem that I am having, is that even though everything is clean with no errors, other processes in the same Docker network cannot talk to the selenium server.

On the other hand, if I create a selenium server using a pre-existing image, like so:

```
docker run -d --network=cdt-net --name cdt-selenium selenium/standalone-firefox:3.4.0-chromium
```

then things are working as expected, and I can connect to the selenium server from other processes in the Docker network.

Anyone know what might be wrong with my bash script or Dockerfile? Perhaps my manually created Selenium server is not listening on the right host?

Here is the complete Dockerfile for reference:

```
FROM openjdk:latest

RUN apt-get update && \
      apt-get -y install sudo


RUN sudo apt-get install -y curl
RUN sudo apt-get install -y apt-utils

RUN sudo apt-get -y update
RUN sudo apt-get -y upgrade

RUN sudo apt-get purge nodejs npm
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | sudo -E bash -
RUN sudo apt-get install -y nodejs   

RUN echo "before nodejs => $(which nodejs)"
RUN echo "before npm => $(which npm)"

RUN sudo ln -s `which nodejs` /usr/bin/node  || echo "ignore error"

RUN mkdir -p /root/cdt-webdriver
WORKDIR /root/cdt-webdriver

COPY start-selenium-server.sh .

RUN rm -rf node_modules   > /dev/null 2>&1
RUN npm init -f || echo "ignore non-zero exit code"  > /dev/null 2>&1
RUN npm install webdriver-manager  > /dev/null 2>&1

ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "/root/cdt-webdriver/start-selenium-server.sh"]
```

Comment: I got this without option `-d`: `docker run --network=cdt-net --name cdt-selenium cdt-selenium` Output:
`/root/cdt-webdriver/start-selenium-server.sh: line 2: ./node_modules/.bin/webdriver-manager: No such file or directory` and
`/root/cdt-webdriver/start-selenium-server.sh: line 3: ./node_modules/.bin/webdriver-manager: No such file or directory`

Comment: yeah sorry, I removed some lines for simplicity from the Dockerfile, just so people would get the gist, I will paste the complete Dockerfile in the original question.

Comment: What do `docker logs cdt-selenium` and `docker ps -f name=cdt-selenium` report after startup? or what happens when you run the container in the foreground, without `-d` ?

Comment: Have you already tried to add `EXPOSE 4444` to your Dockerfile and added option `-p 4444` to `docker run`?

Comment: Yeah maybe that's the problem, but I was thinking that using the --network would obviate the need to do that

Answer (score 1):

You should use `-d` only when you docker images run fine. Before that use `-it`.

Change you `webdriver-manager` to a global install

```
RUN npm install -g webdriver-manager  > /dev/null 2>&1

ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "/root/cdt-webdriver/start-selenium-server.sh"]
```

Also change your `start-selenium-server.sh` to

```
webdriver-manager update
webdriver-manager start
```

And use below to run and check if there are any issues

```
docker run --network=cdt-net --name cdt-selenium -it cdt-selenium
```